# How to search outlook email having string in subject line using python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, outlook, win32com

I want to count last 7 days outlook emails having subject with error types as well as server name. I am new to Python coding.Can someone please help on this?

For example:-
I have mails in my inbox as below subject line:

1. Check for missing backups on CP-TEST-DB2
2. Check deadlock on G-PROD-AUDB
3. There are errors in the SQL Error Log on LF-PTT-DW1
4. Check drive space on CP-TEST-DB1

So, I want to fetch mails with subject line 'Check for missing backups' for each server(e.g.- CP-TEST-DB2, G-PROD-AUDB) and want count on it server wise.
Like how many "Check for missing backups on" mails i have for "CP-TEST-DB2" server.
how many "Check for missing backups on" mails i have for "G-PROD-AUDB" and so on for every server.

how many "Check deadlock on" mails i have for "CP-TEST-DB2" server.
how many "Check deadlock on" mails i have for "G-PROD-AUDB" and so on for every server...
and so on for error type also. 
I have 8 type of sql error alert mail for each 33 servers?

````
import win32com.client
import imp, sys, os, re
import datetime as dt
import time

date_time = dt.datetime.now()
print (date_time)

#list of errors
error = ['There are errors in the SQL Error Log on', 'Check for missing backups on', 'Check drive space on', 'Check memory usage on', 'Check deadlock on ']

#list of server
server = ['TEST-AUDB','TEST-AUDB','EUDB','TEST-EUDB','PROD-AUDB','PROD-EUDB']

#setup range for outlook to search emails (so we don't go through the entire inbox)
lastHourDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days = 7)
#print (lastHourDateTime)

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders.Item(2).Folders['Inbox']

messages = inbox.Items
messages.sort("[ReceivedTime]", True)
lastHourMessages = messages.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" +lastHourDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')+"'")
print ("Current time: "+date_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p'))

for msg in lastHourMessages:
        subject = msg.Subject
        time = msg.ReceivedTime
        print (s1)```
````

Comment: Hey, a couple of things. First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow. Second, your question is not clear enough for me to help, so could you edit the question and try to explain it a little better? Also, the instances and errors in the question text do not match the ones in the code.

Comment: I have explained with example. Please let me know if it works for you .

Comment: Thank you João Amaro for your help.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, it is good practice to accept the answer, which will add to my rep and help me help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex expression:

```
([\-A-Z0-9]+)$
```

which will match 1 or more of every upper case letter, number and dash until the end of the sentence. This covers all the cases you provided in your question, as can be seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/YTG4GU/1).

Next, you can use the `re` module, and iterate over the list of strings, searching for a match using the pattern I've mentioned above, and storing the information in a nested dictionary.

```
import re

# Example strings
strings = ["Check for missing backups on CP-TEST-DB2",
            "Check deadlock on CP-TEST-DB2",
            "Check deadlock on CP-TEST-DB2",
            "Check deadlock on G-PROD-AUDB",
            "There are errors in the SQL Error Log on LF-PTT-DW1",
            "Check drive space on CP-TEST-DB1"]

# Declare empty dictionary
occurrences = {}

# Iterate over all the examples
for string in strings:
    results = re.search('([\-A-Z0-9]+)$', string)
    # Get the server from the regex match
    server = results.group(0)
    # Remove the server from the string and use strip to get rid of the trailing whitespace
    instance = string.replace(server, '').strip()
    # If the server is still not in the dict, insert it manually
    if occurrences.get(server, None) is None:
        occurrences[server] = {instance: 1}
    # If the server is already in the dict, but not the instance, create the key and initial value for the instance
    elif occurrences[server].get(instance, None) is None:
        occurrences[server][instance] = 1
    # Otherwise, just increment the value for the server-instance pair
    else:
        occurrences[server].update({instance : occurrences[server].get(instance, 0) + 1})
print(occurrences)
```

Hope this helps!